# Initialized empty list passed to void function

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass a list to another class. I have my list initialized in my constructor:

```
class _MyFormState extends State {
List<String> arrayOfKeywords = [];
```

In my code the list is being successfully populated and then I need to pass it to a void function:

```
void createPerson(List<String> arrayOfKeywords) async {
```

But in my void function the list is empty, flutter is taking the initialized list, not the updated one. How could I fix that ?

FULL CODE:

```
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final _newPerson = Person();
  // initialize an empty array
  List<String> arrayOfKeywords = [];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Profile')),
        body: Container(
            padding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Builder(
                builder: (context) => Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration:
                            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nom'),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter your first name';
                              }
                            },
                            onChanged: (val) =>
                                setState(() => _newPerson.firstName = val),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                              decoration:
                              InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter your last name.';
                                }
                              },
                              onChanged: (val) =>
                                  setState(() => _newPerson.lastName = val)),
                                                
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  globals.update("nv_personne_nom", (value) => _newPerson.lastName);
                                  globals.update("nv_personne_prenom", (value) => _newPerson.firstName);
                                  print(_newPerson.lastName);
                                  print(_newPerson.firstName);

                         //Building keywords, starting with *
                                  String buildkeywords = "'*'";

                              //Getting the string length
                                 int strlength = _newPerson.lastName.length;
                                  print(strlength);

                                  int i = 2;

                              //starting loop
                                  while (i <= strlength) {
                              // building list
                                  buildkeywords = buildkeywords +"," + "\'" + _newPerson.lastName.substring(0, i) + "\'";

                                    
                                  i = i + 1;
                                  };

                              //Making a list from the built keywords
                            
                    List<String> arrayOfKeywords = buildkeywords.split(',');

                                 print (arrayOfKeywords);

                                  },

                                  child: Text('check')
                              )
                          ),
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    createPerson(arrayOfKeywords);
                                  },

                                  child: Text('save')
                              )
                          ),
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Submitting form')
    )
    );
  }
}

void createPerson(List<String> arrayOfKeywords) async {


  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("personnes")
        .add({
      // 'personne': '',
      // 'categorie': '',
      // 'Intervenant': '',
      // 'Intervenant': (globals["utilisateur"]),
      // 'nom': (globals["lieu"]),
      'prenom': (globals["nv_personne_prenom"]),
      'nom': (globals["nv_personne_nom"]),
      //'keywords': keywords,

    });
   
    print(ref.id);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We cannot know what mistake you made if you don't post your code.

Comment: Edited my question to show the full code. When I write my array to Firestore, it shows as[], like in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> arrayOfKeywords = buildkeywords.split(',');
```

This creates a **new** list, a local variable with the same name as the one you wanted to write to.

This will set your *existing* list:

```
arrayOfKeywords = buildkeywords.split(',');
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much !  I didn't know you could have 2 variables with the same name within the same class.